# How to connect Hibernate with Postgres in Intelij using Maven?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, maven

I have installed Postgres version 10.1 on windows7x64.
I have got a database "mydb" with one table "User" and columns "firstname" and "secondname".
I am using Intelij and Maven.
Below files with content:

App.java

```
package com.hibernateTest;

import org.hibernate.Session;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        User user = new User();

        user.setFirstname("David");
        user.setLastname("Sol");

        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
package com.hibernateTest;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

User:

```
package com.hibernateTest;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Column(name = "firstname", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String username) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @Column(name = "lastname", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb</property>
        <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.hibernateTest.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>HibernateExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>HibernateExample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1203-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Right know when I try to run my application there is an error: "Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.hibernateTest.User". So there is a problem with maping or configuration. Hibernate doesn't see table User or login or password is incorrect? Could you help me please. Thank you very much.

Comment: add @Entity annotation to User class

Comment: I have added @Entity from "org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;" but the error is the same.

Comment: Remove org.hibernate.annotations.Entity and import javax.persistence.Entity

Comment: Map your entity class in your Hibernate.cfg.xml. I.e.: <mapping class="com/hibernateTest/User"/>.